# using ATTACH with Community.CsharpSqlite

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I am currently working on C# with sqlite databases. I am using the Community.CsharpSqlite for the connection between the application and the DB. I want to be able to use the ATTACH command on sqlite to be able to mount another DB.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient/

I am able to do this using the System.Data.Sqlite, but i was wondering if anyone knew how to use it with the Community.CsharpSqlite.

Goal: Query a large database and store the result in a sub database.

Plan : Attach Big database to sub database's connection, using the

ATTACH 'big database' as ToMerge; (in sub DB's connection)

Insert into table Select * from ToMerge.table;

This is the progress i have made using the **System.Data.Sqlite**

```
public static void importData(String fileLoc)
        {
            string SQL = "ATTACH '" + fileLoc + "' AS TOMERGE";
            SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = D:\\sqirl_test\\ir1.db;Version=3");
            con.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(SQL, con);
            int retval = 0;
            try
            {
                retval = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred, your import was not completed.");
            }
            finally
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
            }

            SQL = "INSERT INTO IMAGEREPOSITORY SELECT * FROM TOMERGE.IMAGEREPOSITORY";
            cmd = new SQLiteCommand(SQL, con);
            retval = 0;
            try
            {
                retval = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred, your import was not completed.");
            }
            finally
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: I wanted to do it using the Community.CsharpSqlite port. There was no proper documentation for it, so wanted to know if anyone here had done it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is facing the same issue, here is the solution, community.CsharpSqlite takes the same command as that used for sqlite,

**ATTACH 'db file with location' as toMerge;**

Also quick tip: breakpoints in the sqliteInt_h.cs file would help you debug the error codes from the sqlite files.

```
static int SQLITE_CORRUPT_BKPT()
{
return sqlite3Corrupt();
}
```